# How to create lift function

Tags: scala

I am trying to create the following lift function but I am hitting a brick wall:

```
scala> def liftOff[A,B](f : A => B) : A => Option[B] = _.map(f)
<console>:10: error: value map is not a member of type parameter A
       def liftOff[A,B](f : A => B) : A => Option[B] = _.map(f)
```

I thought I could denote that the type parameter A is mappable but the mappable trait is now deprecated since 2.10. If the input type of the returned function is an Option it's not a problem but that is not what I need:

```
scala> def liftOff[A,B](f : A => B) : Option[A]  => Option[B] = _ map f
liftOff: [A, B](f: A => B)Option[A] => Option[B]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It seems like your question isn't really how to create this function, but how to provide evidence that `A` has a `map` method. Moreover, a `map` method that for some reason returns some `Option[B]`.

Comment: @m-z, is it possible to give the type parameter A an upper bound that denotes it mappable?

Comment: You can use a structural type, which isn't recommended. Or you can use a type class like `scalaz.Functor`, which would require a bit of work depending on what `A` is, and whether or not it has a `Functor[A[_]]` defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you are trying to define is a method that takes a function from A to B, and returns a function from A to Option[B], then you just need to combine f with a function to enclose the result in an Option, such as:

```
def liftOff[A,B](f : A => B) : A => Option[B] = f andThen Option.apply
```

if this isn't what you meant, then you might need to edit your question to make your intent clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to lift* it to the Option type first:

```
scala> def liftOff[A,B](f : A => B) : A => Option[B] = Some(_) map f
liftOff: [A, B](f: A => B)A => Option[B]

scala> liftOff((x:Int) => 2.0 * x)(3)
res6: Option[Double] = Some(6.0)
```

**Note: Here `Some` is the unit/return method lifting A to a monadic (Option) type.*